# Equivalent of Jackson's JsonUnwrapped in kotlinx.serialization

Tags: kotlin, serialization

I have a class such as:

```
@Serializable
data class Example(
   val id: Int
   val items: Map<String, Int>
)

val instance = Example(1, hashMapOf("one" to 1, "two" to 2))
```

How do I make Kotlin serialization lift the keys of the `items` map into the Example object during serialization? If I was using Jackson I would annotate the `items` property with `@JsonUnwrapped`.

I've tried the default serialization and the `items` property is its own key with the hashmap represented as an object:

```
{ 
   "id": 1,
   "items": {
               "one": 1,
               "two": 2
            }
}
```

whereas I would like the object to be serialized like so:

```
{ 
   "id": 1,   
   "one": 1,
   "two": 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
object SortedMapSerializer: KSerializer<Map<String, Int>> {
    private val mapSerializer = MapSerializer(String.serializer(), Int.serializer())
    
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = mapSerializer.descriptor

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Map<String, Int>) {
        mapSerializer.serialize(encoder, value.toSortedMap())
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Map<String, Int> {
        return mapSerializer.deserialize(decoder)
    }
}

@Serializable
class Example(
    @Serializable(with = SortedMapSerializer::class)
    val map: Map<String, Int>
)

fun main() {
    val example = Example(mapOf("b" to 2, "c" to 3, "a" to 1))
    println(Json.encodeToString(example))
}
```

Comment: This prints `{"map":{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}}` rather than `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}` which is what I would want it to be.